# how to catch android force to close

Tags: android

Now i am working json application.The Force close message occured the app is crosed.  so

how to catch force to close error in try catch exception.Help me.....

Comment: Help us to understand you, then perhaps we could help you with your android.

Answer (score 1):

put log.d commands everywhr and check the log messages in the log view....

open window > Android > Log

Answer (score 1):

While defining your message give : throws JSONException
and put the code that raises exception inside try block.
After try block, give Catch statement as :

```
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new JSONException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid surround all cod with try/catch blocks, you can use  thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler [Check it out](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Another way is to use ACRA to get logs Error from your APP,  [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)